# CentOS with both 32bit and 64bit libraries?

Tags: centos, 32bit-64bit

Does anybody know the basic jist of what needs to be done to accomplish this?

Comment: What, exactly, is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the x86_64 version of CentOS. It makes i?86 versions of various libraries available via yum.